# Upload Laravel project to server error 500

Tags: php, laravel

I uploaded my website to my server and now it's returning error 500, I search for more then 5 hours, my server is using php 7.0 and local my project is working with php 7.2

I checked the log and it is returning just 1 error 500 and 2 warnings

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/vhosts/placarama.com.br/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php on line 42

Also,

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

debugging my code, I notice that the error happens in index.php before this code

`$response->send();`

and after this one

`$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);`

maybe here

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);`
```

Comment: You need PHP 7.1: https://github.com/symfony/finder/blob/master/Comparator/NumberComparator.php#L42

Comment: also make sure you set the right permissions on public, storage and bootstrap folders